# Почему npx tsc index.ts и npx tsc дают разный результат?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript

Car.ts

```
function logClass(a: any, b: any) {
  console.log(["logClass", a, b])
}

function logMethod(a: any, b: any) {
  console.log(["logMethod", a, b])
}

export default
@logClass
class Car {
  public constructor() {
  }

  @logMethod
  public run() {
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import Car from "./Car"

const car = new Car()
car.run()
```

npx tsc выдает ошибку

```
Car.ts:18:1 - error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  The runtime will invoke the decorator with 1 arguments, but the decorator expects 2.

18 @logClass
   ~~~~~~~~~

  Car.ts:9:27
    9 function logClass(a: any, b: any) {
                                ~~~~~~
    An argument for 'b' was not provided.


Found 1 error in Car.ts:18
```

npx tsc index.ts нормально компилируется

Если сделать как требуется в тексте ошибки, то наоборот npx tsc не будет компилироваться,
а npx tsc index.ts будет

Почему так происходит и зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже что при указании файла в команде npx tsc не читается tsconfig.json, а там были раскомментированы строки

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

дектраторы работают и без этих строк, но работают по-другому